# unable to convert array data to json when '¿' is there

Tags: ruby, json

**this is my ruby code**

```
require 'json'
a=Array.new
value="¿value"
data=value.gsub('¿','-')
a[0]=data
puts a
puts "json is"
puts jsondata=a.to_json
```

**getting following error**

```
C:\Ruby193>new.rb
C:/Ruby193/New.rb:3: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
C:/Ruby193/New.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting $end
value="┐value"
            ^
```

Answer (score 5):

That's not a JSON problem — Ruby can't decode your source because it contains a multibyte character. By default, Ruby tries to decode files as US-ASCII, but `¿` isn't representable in US-ASCII, so it fails. The solution is to provide a magic comment [as described in the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Encoding.html#label-Script+encoding). Assuming your source file's encoding is UTF-8, you can tell Ruby that like so:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
# ...
value = "¿value"
# ...
```

Comment: i try this 

# encoding: utf-8

require 'json'
a=Array.new
value="¿value"
data=value.gsub('¿','-')
a[0]=data
puts a
puts "json is"

put getting same problem

Comment: @oecprashant: The icktoofay's solution works. Make sure you've added # encoding: UTF-8 at the top of your file.

Comment: ON Ruby IDE aptana , it is working . But on CMD it is not working.
I want to ask why it is?

Comment: @oecprashant: It should be working; I'm not really sure why it isn't working for you. The most important thing to check is that the file really is UTF-8 encoded; UTF-8 isn't the only possible option out there. You could also check to see that Ruby's interpreting the magic comment at all by creating a file lacking special characters and instead only containing the magic comment and `p __ENCODING__`, to see that the output matches whatever encoding you put in the magic comment.

Answer (score 0):

With an **editor or an IDE** the soluton of icktoofay (`# encoding: UTF-8` - in the first line) is perfect.

In a **shell with IRB or PRY** it is difficult to find a working configuration. But there is  a workaround that at least worked for my encoding problem which was to enter German umlaut characters.

**Workaround for PRY**:
In PRY I use the `edit` command to edit the contents of the input buffer 
as described in this [pry wiki page](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/User-Input).
This opens an external editor (you can configure which editor you want). And the editor accepts special characters that can not be entered in PRY directly.